# Use regular expression to update text in MySQL field

Tags: mysql, regex, sql

I have a MySQL table with VARCHAR field `description`. Here's an example value in this field:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThis is the second sentence.
```

I want to change the text so that there is a period and space between the two sentences. I think I can fix this with regex, but I don't know how to use the regex in SQL.

How can I use regex to update a field in MySQL?

Comment: This is just in one field, the objective is to put a period and space between those two sentences. In the current example, the end of first sentence and the beginning of the second sentence have nothing in between to separate them `dogThis`.

Comment: I used VARCHAR for this `description` field. I want both sentences to be saved in the same field but I just want them to be separated with a period and a space. I have not used any SQL, I'm not even sure if it's possible to use SQL statements on this one. Do you know of any other solutions that I can use to crack it?

Comment: See this SQL https://i.imgur.com/SAc29ag.png that gives the expected result from the same field but I don't have time to build an UPDATE statement and make dynamic. I don't do a lot of SQL updates personally and use INSERT statements more but there may be better ways to do this with stored procs, passing arguments, return values, etc. but this was a quick test to confirm it is possible. Building the dynamic UPDATE statement isn't something I have time to work on right now, see if this is anything you can work with. But you will need: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg/downloads

Comment: If you don't get enough attention here with this or this doesn't help you, consider asking a moderator to migrate over to https://stackoverflow.com as there are some really good MySQL query writers there that I've asked for help so many more SQL guys over there for sure. Don't cross-post though and ask for this to be migrated. I'm going to delete my answer since I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish. See here for the [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62449) install instruction if you're running Windows OS as this helped me some with the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MariaDB (most of MySQL is compatible with MariaDB). Then you can use 
regular expression and also back reference. An example is given in documentation.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('James Bond','^(.*) (.*)$','\\2, \\1') AS reorder_name;
```

Gives out as

**reorder_name** as Bond, James

If you want to search in a field; whose data is multiline then above search will not work. For this you have to first change the system variable default_regex_flags. i.e.

```
SET GLOBAL default_regex_flags="DOTALL,MULTILINE";
SET SESSION default_regex_flags="DOTALL,MULTILINE";
```

FYI: By default this system variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/a/986870/2992519):

> No.
>
> But if you have access to your server, you could use a user defined
>   function (UDF) like [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp).